# Does Ubuntu Touch support docking?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, dock, ubuntu-for-android

Are the features of Ubuntu for Android included in Ubuntu touch? Like going into a full desktop? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: What do you mean by "docking" are you talking about using a full desktop when plugged into a monitor, or dock features such as charging and data-transfer?

Comment: I mean using a full desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of Ubuntu Touch’s most appealing features is the ability to dock the device and run a full desktop environment from it. The advantage of that is that all your apps, your movie collection, your music, photos, documents etc. go with you without having to sync between phone and desktop.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>[5 pillars of Ubuntu Touch success](https://web.archive.org/web/20131128004927/http://www.ubuntutouch.info:80/2013/07/5-pillars-of-ubuntu-touch-success.html)</sub>

Comment: It seems like he/she is also confused about the difference of Ubuntu touch and Ubuntu for Android. I'd say Ubuntu for Android is just a beta or developer release which still depends on android.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So are you that Ubuntu Touch on a Samsung Nexus device support docking? So it's not just a planned feature of Ubuntu Edge?

Comment: @karel can you be more specific about the comment, do or not the Samsung Nexus and any device that has docking capability be able to use it using Ubuntu Touch/for android?